# Going through all the cases in a rule list

Tags: data-structures

So, I want to have explainable equations derived from replacement rules.

I made a Mathematica function that does the following, it takes a list of rules, and it applies them (using ReplaceAll), then it gives a list of the rules being taken step by step.

```
FormattedRules[{r -> 3, z -> 5, 
  y -> 3, <|"rule" -> x -> Sqrt[(z + y)/r], "numeric" -> True|>}]
(*
{HoldForm[r == 3], HoldForm[z == 5], HoldForm[y == 3],
 HoldForm[x == Sqrt[(y + z)/r] == 2*Sqrt[2/3] == 1.632993161855452]}
*)
```

This works pretty well, however, there might be a rule with multiple cases, say `{{z->5},{z->-5}}`. This of course, produces a branch, of a tree, since I'm saving all the intermediary steps, that means that all intermediary steps should be saved as well.
So, I want to convert for example the following:

```
{y->5,{x->y^2,x->y+3},z->2x}
```

into

```
{{y->5,x->y^2,z->2x},{y->5,x->y+3,z->2x}}
```

Or for example a more nested example

```
{{y->5,y->1},{x->y^2,x->y+3},z->2x}
```

into

```
{{{y->5,x->y^2,z->2x},{y->5,x->y+3,z->2x}},{{y->1,x->y^2,z->2x},{y->1,x->y+3,z->2x}}}
```

In order to do this I thought about using a tree, but I discovered that trees are not implemented in mathematica, natively. So before creating my own custom functions I figured out, maybe someone knows a less error prone way to approach the problem?

Comment: The latest version (12.1) actually does have binary trees. I don't know if it's useful to you, but take a look: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/BinaryTree.html

Comment: I also noticed that `Distribute[{{y -> 5, y -> 1}, {x -> y^2, x -> y + 3}, z -> 2 x}, List, List]` (to use the last example) almost does what you want, except it doesn't group the lists in the same way.